# Input to Expect Script

Tags: expect

in my test file, I had this line hello$LG. So, if I do

```
`cat /test`
```

It will show in my bash shell - hello$LG

But when I try to do this in my expect script,

```
$> expect test.sh `cat /test`
```

It gives me this {hello$LG} . I don't know why it is getting {}. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Expect is based upon TCL, you should use square brackets to execute code. When trying to execute a shell command you should use either exec or open or spawn.

I am not sure what the test.sh does, but

```
expect [exec test.sh 'cat /test']
```

might just do the trick.

There's more on running other programs from Tcl here:
http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/tutorial/Tcl26.html